# Excel Add date column with dates repeated 24 times

Tags: excel

Here is a sample of my data

```
Hour Index  Visits
    0   67
    1   22
    2   111
    3   22
    4   0
    5   0
    6   22
    7   44
    8   0
    9   89
    10  22
    11  111
    12  44
    13  89
    14  44
    15  111
    16  177
    17  89
    18  44
    19  44
    20  89
    21  22
    22  89
    23  44
    24  133
    25  44
    26  22
    27  22
    28  44
    29  22
    30  44
    31  44
    32  22
```

What I want to do is add two columns. In one column there is the date starting at Jan 1, 2013 and repeats this date for 24 rows until it increments to the next day.  Then I want another column that just displays the month of the previous column.  Here is what it should look like

```
Hour Index  Visits  date    month
0   67  1/1/2013    1
1   22  1/1/2013    1
2   111 1/1/2013    1
3   22  1/1/2013    1
4   0   1/1/2013    1
5   0   1/1/2013    1
6   22  1/1/2013    1
7   44  1/1/2013    1
8   0   1/1/2013    1
9   89  1/1/2013    1
10  22  1/1/2013    1
11  111 1/1/2013    1
12  44  1/1/2013    1
13  89  1/1/2013    1
14  44  1/1/2013    1
15  111 1/1/2013    1
16  177 1/1/2013    1
17  89  1/1/2013    1
18  44  1/1/2013    1
19  44  1/1/2013    1
20  89  1/1/2013    1
21  22  1/1/2013    1
22  89  1/1/2013    1
23  44  1/1/2013    1
24  133 2/1/2013    1
25  44  2/1/2013    1
26  22  2/1/2013    1
27  22  2/1/2013    1
28  44  2/1/2013    1
29  22  2/1/2013    1
30  44  2/1/2013    1
31  44  2/1/2013    1
32  22  2/1/2013    1
```

Comment: Yes they are similar, but I was not able to extrapolate how to do this from those answers. So I posted it as a question.

Comment: Not the same question and not the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your Hours starts from `A2`. Then you can write in date column (column `C`):

```
=DATE(2013,1,1)+INT(A2/24)
```

and drop it down.
Next step, write in month column (Column `D`):

```
=MONTH(C2)
```

and drop it down.

Comment: I wanted the month to increment as well once the number of days in the month is exceded.  Is that possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try now